# Automatically change all values in a column to the next value in a number sequence, even with deletes and inserts in Oracle?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, triggers, increment

I need to automatically update a column in a database to always have a "1,2,3,4,5" sequence regardless whether something is inserted or removed.

so for instance, if I have a table named (ticket) that looks like this:

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1 |
| Randy | 2 |
| Phil | 3 |
| Peggy | 4 |
| Sandy | 5 |

I want it so that if you delete a line, Lets say "Phil", than it would adjust all the columns below like so.

| Name | Number |
| --- | --- |
| John | 1 |
| Randy | 2 |
| Peggy | 3 |
| Sandy | 4 |

Is there a way I can make a trigger do this?

Thank you.

Comment: One strategy is to produce the number in the SELECT query instead of storing it in the table.

Comment: What’s the end goal for this? Making an update of one row effect possibly every other row is not going to be scalable. As suggested already, maybe you want to compute this on select or perhaps a completely different direction is required

Comment: Without knowing more, it sounds like what you're after is a [row_number()](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions137.htm), not a stored value. But that's just a guess. As others said, it'd help to explain your end goal first ....

Comment: Unfortunately it has to work exactly like this and the values need to be stored.

Answer (score 0):

It is easy enough to do, but you've also now converted your database in what amounts to a single user system, but a one row operation will now lock the entire table for the duration of the update.  eg

```
SQL> select *
  2  from   t
  3  order by seq;

ENAME             SEQ
---------- ----------
SMITH               1
ALLEN               2
WARD                3
JONES               4
MARTIN              5
BLAKE               6
CLARK               7
SCOTT               8
KING                9
TURNER             10
ADAMS              11
JAMES              12
FORD               13
MILLER             14

14 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> create or replace
  2  trigger trg after delete or insert on t
  3  declare
  4    type fixuprows is table of t%rowtype index by pls_integer;
  5    r fixuprows;
  6  begin
  7    lock table t in exclusive mode;
  8    select ename, row_number() over ( order by seq ) as newseq
  9    bulk collect into r
 10    from   t ;
 11
 12    forall i in 1 .. r.count
 13      update t
 14      set    seq = r(i).seq
 15      where  ename = r(i).ename;
 16  end;
 17  /

Trigger created.

SQL>
SQL> delete from t
  2  where ename = 'ADAMS';

1 row deleted.

SQL>
SQL> select *
  2  from   t
  3  order by seq;

ENAME             SEQ
---------- ----------
SMITH               1
ALLEN               2
WARD                3
JONES               4
MARTIN              5
BLAKE               6
CLARK               7
SCOTT               8
KING                9
TURNER             10
JAMES              11
FORD               12
MILLER             13

13 rows selected.

SQL>
SQL> insert into t (ename) values ('Connor');

1 row created.

SQL>
SQL> select *
  2  from   t
  3  order by seq;

ENAME             SEQ
---------- ----------
SMITH               1
ALLEN               2
WARD                3
JONES               4
MARTIN              5
BLAKE               6
CLARK               7
SCOTT               8
KING                9
TURNER             10
JAMES              11
FORD               12
MILLER             13
Connor             14

14 rows selected.
```

But please... don't do this. It is a disaster waiting to happen.  I don't think I've ever seen a requirement for this that is not a misinterpretation of the true customer requirement.